How to check equivalence when variables in equations are replaced by their negatives?
In a previous post about checking whether two systems of equations are equivalent, the suggestion was to use the Reduced Row Echelon Form, which was great.
However, I now want to consider an additional class of equivalences that meet either of the following conditions:

Their Reduced Row Echelon Form are identical (as in previous post).
The two systems of equations have the same Reduced Row Echelon Form when any variable or combination of variables is replaced by its negative counterpart.

Note that this should also include the equivalences mentioned in the previous post.
For example, the systems of equations below are not equivalent by criterion 1 but are equivalent according to criterion 2:
s1 = {t + x == 0, y + x - z == 0};
s2 = {t - x == 0, y - x - z == 0}; (* obtained from s1 by changing x to -x *)
s3 = {-t - x == 0, y - x - z == 0}; (* obtained from s1 by changing both x and t to -x and -t *)
s4 = {t - x == 0, y + x + z == 0}; (* obtained from s1 by changing both x and z to -x and -z *)

I would like to collect all systems of equations that are equivalent under either criterion 1 or 2 into a group. Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this or how to check for this type of equivalence?
This is the larger data with 10 variables.
s1 = {x1 + x2 + x3 == 0, x4 + x5 - x6 == 0, x7 + x8 + x9 - x10 == 0}; 
(* Base system *)

s2 = {-x1 + x2 + x3 == 0, x4 - x5 - x6 == 0, x7 + x8 - x9 - x10 == 0}; 
(* obtained from s1 by changing x1, x5, and x9 to -x1, -x5, and -x9 *)

s3 = {x1 - x2 + x3 == 0, -x4 + x5 - x6 == 0, -x7 + x8 + x9 - x10 == 0}; 
(* obtained from s1 by changing x2, x4, and x7 to -x2, -x4, and -x7 *)

s4 = {x1 + x2 - x3 == 0, x4 + x5 + x6 == 0, x7 - x8 + x9 + x10 == 0}; 
(* obtained from s1 by changing x3, x6, and x8 to -x3, -x6, and -x8 *)

s5 = {-x1 - x2 + x3 == 0, -x4 - x5 + x6 == 0, -x7 - x8 + x9 + x10 == 0}; 
(* obtained from s1 by changing x1, x2, x4, x5, x7, and x8 to -x *)

s6 = {x1 - x2 - x3 == 0, -x4 + x5 - x6 == 0, x7 + x8 - x9 - x10 == 0}; 
(* obtained from s1 by changing x2, x3, x4, x9 to -x *)

s7 = {-x1 + x2 - x3 == 0, x4 - x5 + x6 == 0, -x7 + x8 + x9 - x10 == 0}; 
(* obtained from s1 by changing x1, x3, x5, x7, x10 to -x *)

s8 = {-x1 - x2 - x3 == 0, -x4 - x5 + x6 == 0, -x7 - x8 - x9 + x10 == 0}; 
(* obtained from s1 by changing all variables to -x *)

s9 = {x1 + x2 + x3 == 0, -x4 - x5 + x6 == 0, -x7 - x8 + x9 - x10 == 0}; 
(* obtained from s1 by changing x4, x5, x7, x8 to -x *)

s10 = {-x1 - x2 + x3 == 0, x4 + x5 - x6 == 0, x7 - x8 + x9 + x10 == 0}; 
(* obtained from s1 by changing x1, x2, x8, x10 to -x *)

s11 = {x1 - x2 + x3 == 0, -x4 + x5 - x6 == 0, -x7 + x8 - x9 - x10 == 0}; 
(* obtained from s1 by changing x2, x4, x7, x9 to -x *)

s12 = {-x1 + x2 - x3 == 0, x4 - x5 -x6 == 0, x7 - x8 + x9 - x10 == 0}; 
(* obtained from s1 by changing x1, x3, x5, x8 to -x *)

s13 = {x1 + x2 - x3 == 0, -x4 + x5 + x6 == 0, -x7 + x8 + x9 + x10 == 0}; 
(* obtained from s1 by changing x3, x4, x6, x7, x10 to -x *)

s14 = {-x1 + x2 + x3 == 0, x4 - x5 - x6 == 0, x7 - x8 - x9 - x10 == 0}; 
(* obtained from s1 by changing x1, x5, x8, x9 to -x *)

s15 = {x1 - x2 - x3 == 0, -x4 + x5 - x6 == 0, -x7 + x8 - x9 + x10 == 0}; 
(* obtained from s1 by changing x2, x3, x4, x7, x9, x10 to -x *)

s16 = {-x1 - x2 - x3 == 0, x4 + x5 + x6 == 0, x7 + x8 + x9 - x10 == 0}; 
(* obtained from s1 by changing x1, x2, x3 to -x *)

s17 = {x1 + x2 + x3 == 0, -x4 - x5 + x6 == 0, -x7 - x8 - x9 - x10 == 0}; 
(* obtained from s1 by changing x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9 to -x *)

s18 = {-x1 + x2 + x3 == 0, x4 - x5 - x6 == 0, -x7 + x8 - x9 - x10 == 0}; 
(* obtained from s1 by changing x1, x5, x7, x9 to -x *)

s19 = {x1 - x2 + x3 == 0, -x4 + x5 + x6 == 0, x7 - x8 + x9 - x10 == 0}; 
(* obtained from s1 by changing x2, x4, x6, x8 to -x *)

s20 = {-x1 + x2 - x3 == 0, x4 + x5 - x6 == 0, -x7 - x8 - x9 + x10 == 0}; 
(* obtained from s1 by changing x1, x3, x7, x8, x9, x10 to -x *)

s21 = {x1 + x2 - x3 == 0, -x4 - x5 - x6 == 0, x7 + x8 - x9 - x10 == 0}; 
(* obtained from s1 by changing x3, x4, x5, x9 to -x *)

s22 = {-x1 - x2 + x3 == 0, x4 - x5 - x6 == 0, -x7 - x8 + x9 + x10 == 0}; 
(* obtained from s1 by changing x1, x2, x5, x7, x8, x10 to -x *)

s23 = {x1 - x2 + x3 == 0, -x4 + x5 - x6 == 0, x7 - x8 - x9 - x10 == 0}; 
(* obtained from s1 by changing x2, x4, x8, x9 to -x *)

s24 = {-x1 + x2 - x3 == 0, x4 - x5 - x6 == 0, -x7 + x8 + x9 - x10 == 0}; 
(* obtained from s1 by changing x1, x3, x5, x7 to -x *)

s25 = {x1 + x2 + x3 == 0, -x4 + x5 + x6 == 0, x7 + x8 - x9 - x10 == 0}; 
(* obtained from s1 by changing x4, x6, x9 to -x *)

s26 = {-x1 - x2 - x3 == 0, x4 + x5 - x6 == 0, -x7 - x8 + x9 - x10 == 0}; 
(* obtained from s1 by changing x1, x2, x3, x7, x8 to -x *)

s27 = {x1 - x2 - x3 == 0, -x4 - x5 + x6 == 0, x7 - x8 + x9 - x10 == 0}; 
(* obtained from s1 by changing x2, x3, x4, x5, x8 to -x *)

s28 = {-x1 + x2 + x3 == 0, x4 - x5 - x6 == 0, -x7 + x8 - x9 - x10 == 0}; 
(* obtained from s1 by changing x1, x5, x7, x9 to -x *)

s29 = {x1 + x2 - x3 == 0, -x4 + x5 + x6 == 0, x7 - x8 + x9 - x10 == 0}; 
(* obtained from s1 by changing x3, x4, x8 to -x *)

s30 = {-x1 - x2 + x3 == 0, x4 - x5 - x6 == 0, -x7 - x8 + x9 + x10 == 0}; 
(* obtained from s1 by changing x1, x2, x7, x8, x10 to -x *)


As the OP wanted "equivalent or not" answer on large systems , I take a different approach. (My original answer appears in the end.)
ClearAll["Global`*"]; 

ss={s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7,s8,s9,s10,s11,s12,s13,s14,s15,s16,s17,s18,s19,s20,s21,s22,s23,s24,s25,s26,s27,s28,s29,s30};

vars = Variables[ss /. Equal -> Subtract]
(* {x1,x10,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,x9} *) 

ClearAll[normalform]; 
normalform[sys_] := 
 MatrixForm@
  FixedPoint[
   (Transpose[
    Transpose[#]/.{x:{0...,_?Negative,___} :>-x}]
    /. {x:{___,_?Negative,0...}:>-x})&, 
   RowReduce[Normal[CoefficientArrays[sys,vars][[2]]]]
  ];

normalform /@ ss // Short


SameQ @@ %

(* True *) 

So the systems s1,...,s30 are all equivalent.
The condition of OP's equivalence can be stated as: the reduced row echelon form is equal up to overall sign change of columns. I resolved the last ambiguity by flipping the sign of each column whose first nontrivial coefficient is negative.
In normalform[], the outermost MatrixForm@ is added only for the eye's sake. You can remove them.
EDIT: The previous argument was not enough: I overlooked the possibility of overall sign change of rows. In order to obtain a normal form under both row and column sign flips, I used FixedPoint which repeats (1) and (2) until no further change occurs:
(1) flipping the sign of each column whose first nontrivial coefficient is negative.
(2) flipping the sign of each row whose last nontrivial coefficient is negative.
Original Answer
If your linear systems contain not too many variables, to compute Reduced Row Echelon Forms for all possible sign-flip patterns is a possible approach. Of course, you can reduce the size of output by cutting down the size of sign-flip patterns (stored in the variable repls below).
ClearAll["Global`*"];
s1 = {t + x == 0, y + x - z == 0};
s2 = {t - x == 0, y - x - z == 0};
s3 = {-t - x == 0, y - x - z == 0};
s4 = {t - x == 0, y + x + z == 0};
vars = Variables[{s1, s2, s3, s4} /. Equal -> Subtract]

(* {t,x,y,z} *)

repls = ((# -> -#) & /@ #) & /@ Most[Subsets[vars]]

(* {{},{t->-t},{x->-x},{y->-y},{z->-z},{t->-t,x->-x},
    {t->-t,y->-y},{t->-t,z->-z},{x->-x,y->-y},{x->-x,z->-z},
    {y->-y,z->-z},{t->-t,x->-x,y->-y},{t->-t,x->-x,z->-z},
    {t->-t,y->-y,z->-z},{x->-x,y->-y,z->-z}} *)

echeron[sys_]:=MatrixForm[RowReduce[CoefficientArrays[sys,vars][[2]]]];

ans=Last@Reap[Do[Sow[{sys,repl},echeron[sys/.r]],
                 {sys,{s1,s2,s3,s4}},{r,repls}], _ ,List];
Grid[{#[[1]],Grid[#[[2]]]}&/@ans,Frame->All]



Thanks, in my case, there are 10 variables, so it seems possible, but it might take a bit too long since there are 300,000 systems of equations to check.

I see. The number of systems are much larger than I expected. If you don't need info on which variable is flipped, and you just want classify into "equivalent classes", then a more efficient approach is possible. If you want, please give a larger sample of systems.

I don't need information on which variable is flipped. I want to check if two systems of equations are equivalent so I only need the result True or False.  I'll prepare the sample.

I just updated with larger systems of equations.

@internet I revised my answer.

Thanks, that is good. However, it doesn't work for this case (the case in my previous post).
vars = {x, y, z}; normalform /@ {{2 x - 3 y + 4 z == 0, -5 x + 6 y - 7 z ==      0}, {-3 y + 2 x + 4 z == 0, -3 x + 3 y - 3 z == 0}}
so I'm thinking further using RowReduce to compare them.

I added RowReduce like this to cover the cases in my previous post. Does this look good to you. I tried and it works.
normalform[sys_] :=   RowReduce@   Transpose[    Normal[Transpose[CoefficientArrays[sys, vars][[2]]]] /.      x : {0 ..., _?Negative, ___} :> -x]

You are right. In fine tuning my answer, I forgot to put RowReduce. I edited my post.

It looks good. I'll run it on my data before accepting it.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
